# mysql time difference between create_at and updated at

Tags: mysql, time, difference

I have 2 columns in my table created_at and updated_at and would like to know how to return a difference if the time is greater than 20 secs?

Comment: yes it was perfect thanks sorry forgot to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the columns are `datetime` values then using the `timestampdiff` function should work:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,created_at,updated_at) AS diff_in_secs 
FROM table
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,created_at,updated_at) > 20;
```

[Example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8ecad/2).

Comment: Probably want to wrap the WHERE's condition in a `ABS()`.

Comment: @Uueerdo Maybe. I assumed that the `created_at` would always happen before `updated_at` as the semantics suggest, but if my assumption is incorrect the the `abs()` would be a good idea.